# How can I scrape data value?

Tags: web-scraping

Extract from imdb website:

```
<div class="inline-block ratings-imdb-rating" name="ir" data-value="6.9">
    <span class="gloabl-sprite rating-star imdb-rating"></span>
    <strong>6.9</strong>
```

Code using Scrapy

```
 rating = response.css(".global-sprite rating-star imdb-rating::text").extract_first()
```

I was using the above class 'global-sprite rating-star imdb-rating' but it doesn't grab the value 6.9 from the imdb website. How can I grab the value with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Quotation seems to be missing.

```
data-value="6.9"
```

Correct and it should work.